# End Point Not found in WCF Restful Service

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am creating a sample wcf service to test with one of my client. 
I am getting result using SOAP, But REST is not working. It shows "Endpoint Not Found" error. 
Here is my Web.Config for WCF service. Can anybody tells me what's wrong with this config file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
 </system.web>
 <system.serviceModel>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
<endpointBehaviors>
  <behavior name="restbehavior">
    <webHttp/>
  </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>


<services>
  <service name ="s2HCloudService.Service1"
  behaviorConfiguration="web" >

    <endpoint name ="SOAPEndPoint"
    contract ="s2HCloudService.IService1"
    binding ="basicHttpBinding"
    address ="soap" />

    <endpoint name ="RESTEndPoint"
    contract ="s2HCloudService.IService1"
    binding ="webHttpBinding"
    address ="rest"
    behaviorConfiguration ="restbehavior"/>

    <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    address="mex" />
  </service>
</services>

<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
   </protocolMapping>    
   <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  <!--
    To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
    Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
-->
   <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

 </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post your code that tries to access the REST endpoint?

Comment: How are you hosting your WCF service? In IIS, or self-hosting? How are you trying to access your RESTful endpoint?

Comment: Its in visual studio 2012